# When signal emitted from C++ send data to QML

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

How I can do this:
When signal finishedreply(from c++) send variable replydata(from c++) to TextArea(qml)

How i can connect this? Maybe Q_PROPERTY is a good way?
I use Qt 5.3

```
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

SendGetSMS *Connection = new SendGetSMS();


engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("abc1", Connection);

QObject::connect(Connection,&SendGetSMS::finishedReply,engine,...);
```

Comment: Yes.. I don't know how I can send variable to qml through connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html)

in the c++:

```
class Message : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString author READ author WRITE setAuthor NOTIFY authorChanged)
public:
    void setAuthor(const QString &a) {
        if (a != m_author) {
            m_author = a;
            emit authorChanged();
        }
    }
    QString author() const {
        return m_author;
    }
private:
    QString m_author;
};

Message msg;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("msg", &msg);
```

in the qml:

```
Text {
    width: 100; height: 100
    text: msg.author    // invokes Message::author() to get this value

    Component.onCompleted: {
        msg.author = "Jonah"  // invokes Message::setAuthor()
    }
}
```